# Changing default Google Maps max viewport?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I want to show a portion of the world of on my Google map, where the user can zoom in, but if he zooms out, he shouldn't be able to go further out than my default viewport (i.e, if I define Africa, user should be able to zoom into Nigeria but should never see America).